# How to add media player in my QmainWindow widget?

Tags: python, pyqt5

THIS IS THE MAIN UI:

[image: THIS IS THE MAIN UI]

I want to add a media player in this black bordered box. I have no idea how to I integrate predesigned QMediaplayers into my window. This black box is a widget that I have set to promoted to QvideoWidget in order to use it but I have little to no idea how to use it.

MY MAIN WINDOW

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'mainscreen.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.2
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(862, 580)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.Header = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.Header.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 50))
        self.Header.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(239, 128, 0);")
        self.Header.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.WinPanel)
        self.Header.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.Header.setObjectName("Header")
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.Header)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setSpacing(0)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        self.Title_bar_container = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.Header)
        self.Title_bar_container.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(239, 133, 0);")
        self.Title_bar_container.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.Title_bar_container.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.Title_bar_container.setObjectName("Title_bar_container")
        self.Slider = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.Title_bar_container)
        self.Slider.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 71, 52))
        self.Slider.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(239, 133, 0);")
        self.Slider.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.Slider.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.Slider.setObjectName("Slider")
        self.horizontalLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.Slider)
        self.horizontalLayout_4.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout_4.setSpacing(0)
        self.horizontalLayout_4.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_4")
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.Slider)
        self.pushButton_4.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_4.setStyleSheet("\n"
"QPushButton{\n"
"background-color: rgb(239, 133, 0);\n"
"border:none;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton::hover{\n"
"    \n"
"    background-color: rgb(243, 164, 50);\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_4.setText("")
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/icon_pics/png/004-list.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.pushButton_4.setIcon(icon)
        self.pushButton_4.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(24, 24))
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.pushButton_4)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.Title_bar_container)
        self.Top_right_buttons = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.Header)
        self.Top_right_buttons.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 16777215))
        self.Top_right_buttons.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(239, 133, 0);")
        self.Top_right_buttons.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.Top_right_buttons.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.Top_right_buttons.setObjectName("Top_right_buttons")
        self.horizontalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.Top_right_buttons)
        self.horizontalLayout_3.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout_3.setSpacing(0)
        self.horizontalLayout_3.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_3")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.Top_right_buttons)
        self.pushButton.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton.setMouseTracking(False)
        self.pushButton.setWhatsThis("")
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("\n"
"QPushButton{\n"
"background-color: rgb(239, 133, 0);\n"
"border:none;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton::hover{\n"
"    \n"
"    background-color: rgb(243, 164, 50);\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton.setText("")
        icon1 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon1.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/icon_pics/png/001-minimize.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.pushButton.setIcon(icon1)
        self.pushButton.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(24, 24))
        self.pushButton.setFlat(False)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.Top_right_buttons)
        self.pushButton_2.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(239, 133, 0);\n"
"border:none;\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton::hover{\n"
"    \n"
"    background-color: rgb(243, 164, 50);\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_2.setText("")
        icon2 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon2.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/icon_pics/png/003-expand.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.pushButton_2.setIcon(icon2)
        self.pushButton_2.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(24, 24))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.pushButton_2)
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.Top_right_buttons)
        self.pushButton_3.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton_3.setStyleSheet("\n"
"QPushButton{\n"
"background-color: rgb(239, 133, 0);\n"
"border:none;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton::hover{\n"
"    \n"
"    background-color: rgb(243, 164, 50);\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_3.setText("")
        icon3 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon3.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/icon_pics/png/002-remove.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.pushButton_3.setIcon(icon3)
        self.pushButton_3.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(24, 24))
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.pushButton_3)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.Top_right_buttons)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.Header)
        self.Main_body = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.Main_body.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 127);")
        self.Main_body.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.Main_body.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.Main_body.setObjectName("Main_body")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.Main_body)
        self.horizontalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout.setSpacing(0)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.Left_side_menu = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.Main_body)
        self.Left_side_menu.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(70, 16777215))
        self.Left_side_menu.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(239, 128, 0);\n"
"background-color: rgb(243, 164, 50);")
        self.Left_side_menu.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.Left_side_menu.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.Left_side_menu.setObjectName("Left_side_menu")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.Left_side_menu)
        self.Main_screen = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.Main_body)
        self.Main_screen.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(239, 128, 0);\n"
"background-color: rgb(243, 164, 50);")
        self.Main_screen.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.Main_screen.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.Main_screen.setObjectName("Main_screen")
        self.widget = QVideoWidget(self.Main_screen)
        self.widget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 50, 201, 161))
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.Main_screen)
        self.Right_side_menu = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.Main_body)
        self.Right_side_menu.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(70, 16777215))
        self.Right_side_menu.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(239, 128, 0);\n"
"background-color: rgb(243, 164, 50);")
        self.Right_side_menu.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.Right_side_menu.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.Right_side_menu.setObjectName("Right_side_menu")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.Right_side_menu)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.Main_body)
        self.Footer = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.Footer.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 50))
        self.Footer.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(239, 128, 0);\n"
"background-color: rgb(243, 164, 50);")
        self.Footer.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.Footer.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.Footer.setObjectName("Footer")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.Footer)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)



    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
from PyQt5.QtMultimediaWidgets import QVideoWidget
import Icons_rc


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a new file where you create a class that inherits from the appropriate widget and use Ui_MainWindow to fill it, there you must create the QMediaPlayer to set it in the QVideoWidget.

Assuming the file provided by the OP is gui.py then the solution is:

```py
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtMultimedia

from gui import Ui_MainWindow


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.player = QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer(
            self, QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer.VideoSurface
        )
        url = QtCore.QUrl(
            "https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/04/file_example_MP4_1920_18MG.mp4"
        )

        self.player.setMedia(QtMultimedia.QMediaContent(url))

        self.player.setVideoOutput(self.ui.widget)
        self.player.play()


def main(args):
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(args)

    widget = MainWindow()
    widget.show()

    ret = app.exec_()

    sys.exit(ret)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv)
```

Comment: Hi, i have changed the name of the widget to the one i added in my MainWindow but it seems to not display the video. Any particular Reason for that??

Comment: @OsamaJilani I don't know what change you have made but I only rely on the MRE that you have provided, any change in your code is already your responsibility (since you can introduce other errors that I don't want to handle)